# shell script command doubt

Tags: tar

I have a command in my shell script

```
CONFIGS="`tar -tzf ${CONFIGS_ARCHIVE}`"
```

CONFIGS_ARCHIVE is tar.gz file. If the command is executed what will be the value of CONFIGS?

Thanks,
LinuxPenseur

Comment: It's probably easiest to just try it

Comment: which quote do you mean " or ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

` quote is for executing the command. Unless you put that ` quote, shell will treat that command as a regular string.
If you want to execute a command and save it to a variable like you do, you must put that ` quote